# Need values returned from previous month-end date

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

Can someone please guide me as to how this would be done.  I'm using Crystal 2008.

I want to pull in data for the previous month-end and put it in the same row as the current month, so there will be two figure columns: one with the Month-End figures and the other will be Previous Month-End Figures.  I want it to look like this:

```
Month-End       Account     Figure      Prev Month-End Figure
1/31/2014       21A3233     11      
2/28/2014       3285592     22          11
3/31/2014       64EG544     33          22
4/30/2014       E5VG96A     44          33
5/31/2014       POIUE52     55          44
6/30/2014       8889947     66          55
7/31/2014       P645252     77          66
8/31/2014       05EU6AB     88          77
9/30/2014       888E658     99          88
```

How would I get the Prev Month-End Figures based on the Month-End dates in the first column?

Comment: is the requirement a generic one or you need only for these dates?

Comment: It will be for any dates.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a formula `@Last Day` and write below code to get last day of previous month:

```
DateSerial(year({Month-End }),Month({Month-End }),1)-1
```

Now create a one more formula `@Data` to get the data of the last day of previous month:

```
if ({Month-End }=DateSerial(year({Month-End }),Month({Month-End }),1)-1)
then Figure
```

Place the formula `@Data` at the column `Prev Month-End Figure`

Comment: The previous month date shows but 2/28/2014 has a value of 22, not 11.

Comment: are you using any grouping what is your report structure?

Comment: No, no grouping.  Everything is in details, however I am linking two tables.

Comment: can you post prev month end figure formula?

Comment: It's simply the month-end figure but for the previous month. The formula is what I'm requesting.  There's no calculation, just Figure.

Comment: I'm looking for a formula that says if monthend=2/28/2014 then prevmonthendfigure=11.

Likewise, if monthend=3/31/2014 the prevmonthendfigure=22.

The results 11 and 22 would fall under the Prev Month-End Figure column.

Comment: My solution should give you the expected output

Comment: Just tried it with one straightforward database with no grouping, etc. and no luck.  When I browse data there is just one value of 0.0.  The values in the Month-End Figure are all 0.00.

I appreciate you trying to help me and as you can probably tell, this is not my forte.

Comment: I get a result back when I substitute your dateserial formula with dateserial(2014,02,28)